How to debug ggraph error: ‹arguments have different crs›?
I came across sfnetworks and ggraph very recently and cannot make sense of the error output by ggraph ‹arguments have different crs›, thus, neither remediation is possible. Any suggestion appreciated.
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.12.1, GDAL 3.8.4, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(sfnetworks)
library(ggraph)
ss <- structure(list(ORD_STRA = c(1L, 1L, 2L), geom = structure(list(
  structure(c(
    35.4971612799067, 35.4994489386804, 35.5030573778628,
    35.5201326954102, 35.5345664521399, 35.5402582246556, 35.5417833305048,
    35.5376166638381, 35.5391417696872, 35.5370584363538, 35.5385835422029,
    20.5745535279332, 20.5660158691596, 20.5639325358262, 20.5685078533735,
    20.5601745200402, 20.5616996258893, 20.5560078533735, 20.5487909750086,
    20.5430992024929, 20.5394907633104, 20.5337989907947
  ), dim = c(
    11L,
    2L
  ), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(
    c(
      35.5202622325487,
      35.5256748913223, 20.5395655516122, 20.5364405516123
    ),
    dim = c(2L, 2L),
    class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")
  ), structure(c(
    35.5256748913223,
    35.5328917696872, 35.5385835422029, 20.5364405516123, 20.5322738849456,
    20.5337989907947
  ), dim = 3:2, class = c(
    "XY", "LINESTRING",
    "sfg"
  ))
), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(
  xmin = 35.4971612799067,
  ymin = 20.5322738849456, xmax = 35.5417833305048, ymax = 20.5745535279332
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
  input = "EPSG:4326",
  wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"
), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  3L
), sf_column = "geom", agr = structure(c(ORD_STRA = NA_integer_), levels = c(
  "constant",
  "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"), class = c(
  "sf",
  "data.frame"
))
ggplot(ss) + 
  geom_sf()


n.ss = as_sfnetwork(ss)
ggraph(n.ss, layout = "tree") +
  geom_node_point(size = 1) +
  geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(length = unit(2, 'mm'), ends = "first"),
                 end_cap = circle(2, 'mm'),
                 start_cap = circle(2, 'mm')) +
  theme_graph()
#> Error: arguments have different crs

Here my sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] shiny_1.8.1.1    transformr_0.1.5 lubridate_1.9.3  forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.1   
 [6] purrr_1.0.2      readr_2.1.5      tidyr_1.3.1      tibble_3.2.1     tidyverse_2.0.0 
[11] cowplot_1.1.3    ggraph_2.2.1     ggplot2_3.5.1    sfnetworks_0.6.4 dplyr_1.1.4     
[16] terra_1.7-71     sf_1.0-16       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.1   viridisLite_0.4.2  farver_2.1.2       viridis_0.6.5     
 [5] R.utils_2.12.3     fastmap_1.1.1      tweenr_2.0.3       promises_1.3.0    
 [9] reprex_2.1.0       digest_0.6.35      mime_0.12          timechange_0.3.0  
[13] lifecycle_1.0.4    processx_3.8.4     magrittr_2.0.3     compiler_4.4.0    
[17] sass_0.4.9         rlang_1.1.3        tools_4.4.0        igraph_2.0.3      
[21] utf8_1.2.4         yaml_2.3.8         knitr_1.46         labeling_0.4.3    
[25] graphlayouts_1.1.1 classInt_0.4-10    KernSmooth_2.23-22 miniUI_0.1.1.1    
[29] R.cache_0.16.0     withr_3.0.0        R.oo_1.26.0        grid_4.4.0        
[33] polyclip_1.10-6    fansi_1.0.6        xtable_1.8-4       e1071_1.7-14      
[37] colorspace_2.1-0   scales_1.3.0       MASS_7.3-60.2      cli_3.6.2         
[41] rmarkdown_2.26     crayon_1.5.2       generics_0.1.3     rstudioapi_0.16.0 
[45] tzdb_0.4.0         DBI_1.2.2          cachem_1.0.8       ggforce_0.4.2     
[49] proxy_0.4-27       s2_1.1.6           vctrs_0.6.5        Matrix_1.7-0      
[53] jsonlite_1.8.8     callr_3.7.6        hms_1.1.3          ggrepel_0.9.5     
[57] jquerylib_0.1.4    clipr_0.8.0        units_0.8-5        glue_1.7.0        
[61] lwgeom_0.2-14      ps_1.7.6           codetools_0.2-20   stringi_1.8.3     
[65] gtable_0.3.5       later_1.3.2        munsell_0.5.1      styler_1.10.3     
[69] pillar_1.9.0       htmltools_0.5.8.1  R6_2.5.1           wk_0.9.1          
[73] sfheaders_0.4.4    tidygraph_1.3.1    lpSolve_5.6.20     evaluate_0.23     
[77] lattice_0.22-6     R.methodsS3_1.8.2  memoise_2.0.1      bslib_0.7.0       
[81] httpuv_1.6.15      class_7.3-22       Rcpp_1.0.12        gridExtra_2.3     
[85] xfun_0.43          fs_1.6.4           pkgconfig_2.0.3 

I have tried to graph another subsection of the network, e.g. only taking the last two features from ss does not produces the error.

Hi! I think that the best way to approach the problem would be creating a new issue in the GitHub page of ggraph and/or sfnetworks posting the exact same question. I'm not sure this is a bug but, at least, the error message is not clear. btw: did you install the latest github version of ggraph?

@agila I suspect CRS refers to co-ordinate reference system.  In which case, the meaning is pretty clear, even if the message is not that informative.

@agila Yes, I thought to do so, however, since the problem could originate from ggraph or sfnetworks, I decided to ask for advice on StackOverflow first. I use ggraph_2.2.1, i.e. the latest version.

@Limey Yes CRS means coordinate reference system, but what should have/is having another CRS, the features, if so how would this be encoded?
